# Blob Data through a Stored Procedure

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, blob

I have a Stored Procedure that takes blob data (VarBinary) as a parameter I can't get it to work with TADOStoredProc though.

The Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddToSolve]  @SolveData VarBinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.ToSolve (Data, SolveStatus)
  VALUES (@SolveData, 0)
END
```

Here are the two things I tried.

This first one fails finding the Field, what am I Missing

```
procedure AddItem(dbCon : TADOConnection; sourcePath : String);
var
  addProc    : TADOStoredProc;
  field      : TField;
  dataStream : TFileStream;
  blobStream : TStream;

begin
  if FileExists(sourcePath) then
  begin
    dataStream := TFileStream.Create(sourcePath, fmOpenREad or fmShareDenyNone);

    try
      addProc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
      addProc.Connection    := dbCon;
      addProc.ProcedureName := 'spAddToSolve';
      field := addProc.FieldByName('@SolveData'); //Field'@SolveData' not found
      blobStream := addProc.CreateBlobStream(field, bmWrite);
      blobStream.CopyFrom(dataStream, dataStream.Size);
      addProc.Open;

    finally
      addProc.Free();
      dataStream.Free();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Not sure how to get the method to work, I don't know how to get the stream data into the param value.

```
procedure AddItem(dbCon : TADOConnection; sourcePath : String);
var
  addProc    : TADOStoredProc;
  param      : TParameter;
  field      : TField;
  dataStream : TFileStream;

begin
  if FileExists(sourcePath) then
  begin
    dataStream := TFileStream.Create(sourcePath, fmOpenREad or fmShareDenyNone);

    try
      addProc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
      addProc.Connection    := dbCon;
      addProc.ProcedureName := 'spAddToSolve';
      param := addProc.Parameters.AddParameter;
      param.Name := '@SolveData';
      param.DataType := ftBlob;
      //not sure what to do next
      param.Value := dataStream; //Types are not compatable
      addProc.Open;

    finally
      addProc.Free();
      dataStream.Free();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second try is on the right track. This should work:

```
param.DataType := ftBlob;
param.LoadFromStream(dataStream);
```

Comment: It works and adds an item to the DB, but on the AddProc.Open I get and exception "Operation aborted" do you know why?

Comment: I see you got an answer to the question you asked in your comment in your other question. :-)